# C# LINQ JOIN LAMBDA Add list of columns from second joined table

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I have a linq query that joins 3 tables, which there is a left outer join on the 2nd table. I am stuck on how to add a few columns from the 2nd table to my output object.

What I have so far is the following

I am stuck for each user record, there is a List that could be 0 to many records.
How do I add those list of selected columns from the office table based on office.userId that matches user.userId?
for example, I need to select from office table, officeSuiteNumber, officeName, officeStartDate, officeEndDate?

I prefer to add it this query instead of looping again and adding the list to each record and adding more processing time.

Thanks for any help.

```
var result = this.dbContext.User
                    .GroupJoin(this.dbContext.Office,
                        user => user.userId,
                        office => office.userId,
                        (user, office) => new { user, office }
                    )
                    .SelectMany(
                        user_office_left => user_office_left.office.DefaultIfEmpty(),
                        (user_office_left, office) => new { user_office_left, office }
                    )
                    .Join(this.dbContext.Dept,
                        user_office => user_office.user_office_left.user.DivisionId,
                        dept=> division.DivisionId,
                        (emp_office, dept) => new { emp_office, dept}
                    )
                    .Select(joined => new MyViewModel
                    {

                        userId = joined.user_office.user_offce_left.user.userId,
                        LastNm = joined.user_office.user_offce_left.user.LastNm,
                        FirstNm = joined.user_office.user_offce_left.user.FirstNm,
                        Title = joined.user_office.user_offce_left.user.Title,
                        DivisionNm = joined.division.ShortDivisionNm,
                       
                        offices = ???? // how to add the list of office that could be 0 to many records 
 
                    }).ToList();
```

Comment: Why do not use Query syntax?

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv What difference would that make?

Comment: What if you did `AsEnumerable` before final `Select` to pull data to client side, then `GroupBy` to undo `SelectMany` than you can work with groups... you really want groupjoin directly, but that can't be translated to SQL - so consider how you want the SQL output to be and use that query, then translate to objects in LINQ.

Comment: @NetMage, readability and refactoring. Still cannot predict which SQL will be generated from this mess of projections.

Comment: Do you really need joins here? Show in question your model. It will be easier to understand how to make query properly especially if there are any navigation properties.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv I would suggest readability of query syntax over fluent syntax is subjective. I would generally say mostly in the case of using `let` is it better / easier.

Comment: Your headline is possible. The final select could take place without the extra "select" in line: (emp_office, dept) => new { emp_office, dept}. BUT: you flattened the offices with the first "SelectMany" and want in the final result many lists of offices. This isnot how joins work. You could get the single offices there.